# Android NFC start service

Tags: android, service, nfc

I'm curious if Android `NFC service` allows the developer to start a `Service` (or `IntentService` for that matter) when `NFC` tag is scanned?

From Android Developers:

> When a device scans a tag that has `NDEF` data on it, but could not be
>   mapped to a `MIME` or `URI`, the tag dispatch system tries to start an
>   **activity** with the `ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED` intent.

It appears that only a new Activity can be launched, not Service, although it could receive the same Intent filter.

Comment: No, one cannot start a service from a scanned tag or a received Android Beam message. See also comment to http://stackoverflow.com/a/9490726/1202968

Comment: @NFC guy, please consider post an answer, rather than comment

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98955/190880

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although not the direct method, you could have a barebones `Activity` that will immediately start a service, then quit:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  Context con = getApplicationContext();
  Intent srv = new Intent(con, TargetService.class);
  con.startService(srv);
  finish();
}
```

Comment: Do not forget to add the Tag extra to the service intent as well, if you want to interact with the tag from the service.