# Android NFC read Tags issue. Activity starts each time on data received

Tags: android, android-activity, tags, nfc, rfid

I have 2 issues with reading NFC Tags.

First is Tag Read Activity creates each time when tag received.

And second issue is activity opens in full screen window, not under Tab Host Activity, but first issue is worst.

What do I do ( AndroidManifest.xml ):

```
<activity
    android:name="readingActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and readingActivity.cs:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("W", "onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.readingActivity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d("W", "onResume");

        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, getIntent(), 0);
         NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this).enableForegroundDispatch(this, intent, 
                  null, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this) != null)
        NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this).disableForegroundDispatch(this);
    }
```

Logs:

```
02-28 18:22:19.949: D/W(4513): onCreate

02-28 18:22:19.949: D/W(4513): onResume

02-28 18:22:21.078: D/W(4513): onCreate

02-28 18:22:21.082: D/W(4513): onResume
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in the `PendingIntent`. The `getIntent()` retrieves the `Intent` that started your `Activity`, so  passing it to the `PendingIntent` will result in starting it another time.

Instead of `getIntent()` use something like `new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), this.getClass())`.

Comment: Is there any ability to handle NFC in background ?