# Can already started Android Service receive NFC tag in the form of Intent?

Tags: android, android-service, nfc

This is a related question to:
[Android NFC start service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819098/android-nfc-start-service)

In Android, can an already started service (class that extends Service) receive an Intent when an NDEF tag is scanned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a service cannot receive an intent from a scanned tag or a received Android Beam message.

Comment: Are there any "normal" workarounds to this limitation? Maybe you can give some advice on how service can get nfc tag without fake activity?

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can make a minimal activity that receives the NDEF intent and starts a custom service. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12845204/539443).